# How to add a variable that estimate the proportion of days someone has been seen since the first time

Tags: r, dplyr

The dataframe `df1` summarizes the date when someone has been seen. I want to create a column that indicates the proportion of days that this person has been seen since the first time.

As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(ID=c("Peter", "Anna", "Sophie", "Peter", "Anna", "Sophie", "Peter", "Anna", "Sophie", "Peter", "Anna", "Sophie", "Peter", "Anna", "Sophie"),
                 Date= c("2016-08-20","2016-08-20","2016-08-23","2016-08-21","2016-08-23","2016-08-24","2016-08-23","2016-08-23","2016-08-25","2016-08-27","2016-08-28","2016-08-26","2016-08-27","2016-08-29","2016-08-30"))
df1$Date<- as.Date(df1$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df1

       ID       Date
1   Peter 2016-08-20
2    Anna 2016-08-20
3  Sophie 2016-08-23
4   Peter 2016-08-21
5    Anna 2016-08-23
6  Sophie 2016-08-24
7   Peter 2016-08-23
8    Anna 2016-08-23
9  Sophie 2016-08-25
10  Peter 2016-08-27
11   Anna 2016-08-28
12 Sophie 2016-08-26
13  Peter 2016-08-27
14   Anna 2016-08-29
15 Sophie 2016-08-30
```

Important: for each person, the first time seen varies.

I would expect this (I did the calculations manually so there might be some mistakes):

```
> df1
       ID       Date Prop_days_seen
1   Peter 2016-08-20           1.00  # 1/1 (First time will always be 1)
2    Anna 2016-08-20           1.00  # 1/1 (First time will always be 1)
3  Sophie 2016-08-23           1.00  # 1/1 (First time will always be 1)
4   Peter 2016-08-21           1.00  # 2/2
5    Anna 2016-08-23           0.50  # 2/4 (two days seen out of 4 days that she could have been seen)
6  Sophie 2016-08-24           1.00  # 2/2 (two days seen out of 2 days she could have been seen)
7   Peter 2016-08-23           0.75  # 3/4
8    Anna 2016-08-23           0.50  # So on...
9  Sophie 2016-08-25           1.00
10  Peter 2016-08-27           0.50
11   Anna 2016-08-28           0.33
12 Sophie 2016-08-26           1.00
13  Peter 2016-08-27           0.50
14   Anna 2016-08-29           0.40
15 Sophie 2016-08-30           0.62
```

Does anyone know how to do it in R?

Comment: Can you show the calculation method or the logic used (if the calculation is not correct)

Comment: Ei @akrun, I add the logic behind this in the desired `df1`. Basically, what I need is to divide the number of different days that the person has been seen by the total number of days in which this person could have been seen (and hence, the latter depends on the first time that each person has been seen).

Comment: For `Anna`, second value is 2/4.  I guess the numerator is the sequence and denominator as 4th day? "2016-08-20", "2016-08-23".   For third value, the date is "2016-08-28", so, is it 3/9?

Comment: Yes, the numerator is the unique days that the person has been seen and the denominator is the maximum number of days she could have been seen since the first time she was seen. In this example, she was seen 2 days (the 20th and the 23rd) out of the 4 days that she could have been seen (from the 20th until the 23rd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be

```
library(zoo)
df1$Prop_days_seen <- round(unsplit(lapply(split(df1$Date, df1$ID), function(x) {
      i1 <- cumsum(c(1, as.integer(diff(x))))
      i2 <- !duplicated(i1);v1 <- numeric(length(x))
      v1[!i2] <- NA
      v1[i2] <- seq_along(x[i2])/i1[i2]
      na.locf(v1) }), df1$ID), 2)

df1
#       ID       Date Prop_days_seen
#1   Peter 2016-08-20           1.00
#2    Anna 2016-08-20           1.00
#3  Sophie 2016-08-23           1.00
#4   Peter 2016-08-21           1.00
#5    Anna 2016-08-23           0.50
#6  Sophie 2016-08-24           1.00
#7   Peter 2016-08-23           0.75
#8    Anna 2016-08-23           0.50
#9  Sophie 2016-08-25           1.00
#10  Peter 2016-08-27           0.50
#11   Anna 2016-08-28           0.33
#12 Sophie 2016-08-26           1.00
#13  Peter 2016-08-27           0.50
#14   Anna 2016-08-29           0.40
#15 Sophie 2016-08-30           0.62
```

---

Also, this can be made more compact

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(n1 = cumsum(c(1, as.integer(diff(Date)))),  
         Prop_days_seen = cumsum(!duplicated(n1))/n1)  %>% 
  select(-n1)
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#   ID     Date       Prop_days_seen
#   <fct>  <date>              <dbl>
# 1 Peter  2016-08-20          1    
# 2 Anna   2016-08-20          1    
# 3 Sophie 2016-08-23          1    
# 4 Peter  2016-08-21          1    
# 5 Anna   2016-08-23          0.5  
# 6 Sophie 2016-08-24          1    
# 7 Peter  2016-08-23          0.75 
# 8 Anna   2016-08-23          0.5  
# 9 Sophie 2016-08-25          1    
#10 Peter  2016-08-27          0.5  
#11 Anna   2016-08-28          0.333
#12 Sophie 2016-08-26          1    
#13 Peter  2016-08-27          0.5  
#14 Anna   2016-08-29          0.4  
#15 Sophie 2016-08-30          0.625
```

Comment: There is something wrong... For instance, for Anna, in the date "2016-08-28" should appear `0.33` since she has been seen 3 out of 9 days (she was started to be seen on "2016-08-20" and she has been seen 3 different days since then, the 20th, the 23rd and the 28th). Do you know why?

Comment: Another issue, two rows for the same person and with the same date should have the same value!