# How to estimate percent of time seen depending on the variables "Datetime" and "Number of times seen per hour"

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

In this post ([How to add a variable that estimate the proportion of days someone has been seen since the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923796/how-to-add-a-variable-that-estimate-the-proportion-of-days-someone-has-been-seen?noredirect=1#comment100390111_56923796)) I asked something with a similar final goal, but here the dataframe is entirely different.

Here, `df1` summarises per hour (`Datetime`) the number of times that a specific animal (`ID`) has been seen (`Times_seen_per_hour`) within a particular area of interest.  Since we know if the animal was in this area at this hour, we also created the column `Presence`, that indicates if the animal was in the area where we can detect it.

I want to know the proportion of hours that the animal was detected regarding the total number of hours that we know the animal was in the area.

Here, an example of what I have now:

```
df1<- data.frame(Datetime= ymd_hms(c("2019-05-20 12:00:00","2019-05-20 12:00:00","2019-05-20 13:00:00","2019-05-20 13:00:00","2019-05-20 14:00:00","2019-05-20 14:00:00","2019-05-20 15:00:00","2019-05-20 15:00:00","2019-05-20 16:00:00","2019-05-20 16:00:00","2019-05-20 17:00:00","2019-05-20 17:00:00","2019-05-20 18:00:00","2019-05-20 18:00:00","2019-05-20 19:00:00","2019-05-20 19:00:00")),
                 ID= c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 Times_seen_per_hour=c(3,0,0,4,2,1,3,2,1,0,0,0,7,0,4,1),
                 Presence= c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
df1

              Datetime ID Times_seen_per_hour Presence
1  2019-05-20 12:00:00  1                   3     TRUE
2  2019-05-20 12:00:00  2                   0    FALSE
3  2019-05-20 13:00:00  1                   0     TRUE
4  2019-05-20 13:00:00  2                   4     TRUE
5  2019-05-20 14:00:00  1                   2     TRUE
6  2019-05-20 14:00:00  2                   1     TRUE
7  2019-05-20 15:00:00  1                   3     TRUE
8  2019-05-20 15:00:00  2                   2     TRUE
9  2019-05-20 16:00:00  1                   1     TRUE
10 2019-05-20 16:00:00  2                   0    FALSE
11 2019-05-20 17:00:00  1                   0     TRUE
12 2019-05-20 17:00:00  2                   0    FALSE
13 2019-05-20 18:00:00  1                   7     TRUE
14 2019-05-20 18:00:00  2                   0     TRUE
15 2019-05-20 19:00:00  1                   4     TRUE
16 2019-05-20 19:00:00  2                   1     TRUE
```

As mentioned, I need to create a new variable called `Prop_hours_seen` that indicates the proportion of hours that the animal has been seen with regard the total number of hours we know the animal was there (`Presence == TRUE`).

I would expect this:

```
> df1
              Datetime ID Times_seen_per_hour Presence Prop_hours_seen
1  2019-05-20 12:00:00  1                   3     TRUE            1.00 # We divide number of hours seen between total number of hours it could have been seen, that is 1/1.
2  2019-05-20 12:00:00  2                   0    FALSE              NA # We don't consider this hour since the animal wasn't in our area of interest.
3  2019-05-20 13:00:00  1                   0     TRUE            0.50 # We divide number of hours seen (it was seen 1 hour) between total number of hours it could have been seen (it could have been seen at 12:00:00 and at 13:00:00), that is 1/2=0.5.
4  2019-05-20 13:00:00  2                   4     TRUE            1.00
5  2019-05-20 14:00:00  1                   2     TRUE            0.66
6  2019-05-20 14:00:00  2                   1     TRUE            1.00
7  2019-05-20 15:00:00  1                   3     TRUE            0.75
8  2019-05-20 15:00:00  2                   2     TRUE            1.00
9  2019-05-20 16:00:00  1                   1     TRUE            0.80
10 2019-05-20 16:00:00  2                   0    FALSE              NA
11 2019-05-20 17:00:00  1                   0     TRUE            0.66
12 2019-05-20 17:00:00  2                   0    FALSE              NA
13 2019-05-20 18:00:00  1                   7     TRUE            0.71
14 2019-05-20 18:00:00  2                   0     TRUE            0.75
15 2019-05-20 19:00:00  1                   4     TRUE            0.75
16 2019-05-20 19:00:00  2                   1     TRUE            0.80
```

I know this is complex to understand, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Why do you have `Times_seen_per_hour` being 0 but Presence is `TRUE`? If it's 0 shouldn't it be `FALSE`?

Comment: Isn't this similar to the earlier question?

Comment: Thanks. No, I work with fishes. Presence == TRUE means that the fish was in my area of interest and Presence== FALSE means that the fish was out of this area. But that the fish is in my area doesn't mean that we detected it with our eyes because sometimes they are hidden. So, I want to know the proportion of hours we can see the fish with regard the total number of hours we know that the fish is there. Do you understand?

Comment: "We divide number of hours seen (it was seen 1 hour)" - but that ID is seen in eight other hours?

Comment: The difference with other dataframes I posed is that here I have a row per individual and per hour although the fish is not there. If `Times_seen_per_hour` is `0` and `Presence` is `FALSE`, means that the fish wasn't there. But if  `Times_seen_per_hour` is `0` and `Presence` is `TRUE`, means that it was there and we couldn't see it. So I have to manage those things here in order to get what I want...

Comment: @zacdav, I meant until this row. Do you understand? At `12:00:00` the animal could have been seen at `12:00:00`, so the total number of hours in which the animal could have been seen is `1`. For `ID` number `1` in row number 3, at `13:00:00` it could have been seen at two different hours (at `12:00:00` and at `13:00:00`). Do you understand? On each row, I consider the times before, not the times that come later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to match your desired output.
Be warned this assumes every hour will have a row `1:length(Datetime)`.

```
df1 %>%
  arrange(ID, Datetime) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(hours_passed = 1:length(Datetime),
         hours_seen = cumsum(Times_seen_per_hour > 0),
         cumulative_presence = cumsum(Presence),
         prop_hours_seen = hours_seen / cumulative_presence,
         prop_hours_seen = ifelse(Presence, prop_hours_seen, NA)) %>%
  arrange(Datetime, ID)
```

---

```
Datetime               ID Times_seen_per_hour Presence prop_hours_seen
   <dttm>              <dbl>               <dbl> <lgl>              <dbl>
 1 2019-05-20 12:00:00     1                   3 TRUE               1    
 2 2019-05-20 12:00:00     2                   0 FALSE             NA    
 3 2019-05-20 13:00:00     1                   0 TRUE               0.5  
 4 2019-05-20 13:00:00     2                   4 TRUE               1    
 5 2019-05-20 14:00:00     1                   2 TRUE               0.667
 6 2019-05-20 14:00:00     2                   1 TRUE               1    
 7 2019-05-20 15:00:00     1                   3 TRUE               0.75 
 8 2019-05-20 15:00:00     2                   2 TRUE               1    
 9 2019-05-20 16:00:00     1                   1 TRUE               0.8  
10 2019-05-20 16:00:00     2                   0 FALSE             NA    
11 2019-05-20 17:00:00     1                   0 TRUE               0.667
12 2019-05-20 17:00:00     2                   0 FALSE             NA    
13 2019-05-20 18:00:00     1                   7 TRUE               0.714
14 2019-05-20 18:00:00     2                   0 TRUE               0.75 
15 2019-05-20 19:00:00     1                   4 TRUE               0.75 
16 2019-05-20 19:00:00     2                   1 TRUE               0.8
```

Comment: @ zacdav, Do you know how to summarize by ID the number of distinct hours that the fish was seen and the number of hours in total that the fish was in our area?